# How to get all the tweets from the specific trend in twitter from tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

I have a requirement to get all the tweets from the specific trend in twitter.

```
Ex: api.get_all_tweets(trend="ABCD")
```

How can I achieve this with tweepy?

Comment: Have you considered [looking at the documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be guaranteed to capture all tweets. Twitter reserves the right to send you whatever they feel like. For something that is tweeted about infrequently like #upsidedownwalrus you'd probably get all of them, but for something that is a trending topic, you will only ever receive a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter API has limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) on what you can retrieve. If you require a census of posted Tweets, you'll need to pay for a service that provides such, but they are few and far between as they need to actively respect deletions.